# coding mental block, wants inspiration from beautiful coding

Tags: c++, git, github

I'm having a coding mental block and wish to draw inspiration from other's coding. Where can I find beautiful coding (elegant, succinct, self-documenting) to refresh my mind. Github can be a place to start but I don't know authors to look for.

Comment: [We have a site specifically for these types of questions.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not what you had in mind, but the book [Beautiful Code](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510046) is certainly worth consideration.

Comment: Definitely some good stuff in there.

Comment: That indeed looks like an interesting book.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other post, I'd add maybe checking out some other languages.  You'll find beautiful concepts and new ways to program in Scheme, Haskell, Ocaml, Clojure, Erlang, etc...  Some of those languages have features which you can apply to C++, and some of them make really nice examples in their implementation.